# Ruby On Rails Users Ranking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have app with gem acts_as_votable. Every post created by user has upvotes and downvotes.

I am using Sqlite3 on test and Postgresql on development, production.

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def upvote
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.liked_by current_user
 redirect_to posts_path
end

def downvote
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.downvote_from current_user
 redirect_to posts_path
end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def ranking
  @users = User.all
end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 resources :posts do

 member do

    put "like" => "posts#upvote"
    put "unlike" => "posts#downvote"

 end

end
```

ranking.html.erb

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user,index| %>

<div class="panel panel-default col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 right">

<div class="center">

    <h4><b>#<%= index+1 %><b></h4>

</div>


<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left margin-left">

  <%if user.banned? %>
  <h5 class="red left">[BANNED]</h5>
  <%end%>
  <h4> <%=link_to user.name, user%></h4>

</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right margin-right">

  <h4>Points:<%= user.posts.sum(&:cached_votes_score)%></h4>

</ul>
```

Is there a simple way to create a users ranking sorted by points for posts?

Comment: What DB do you use?

Comment: sqlite3 on test and postgre on production,development

Answer (score 1):

`PostgreSQL` dependent solution based on [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html):

```
# ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY votes_sum DESC, id ASC ) - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
# DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY votes_sum DESC )         - 1, 1, 2, 2, 3
# RANK()       OVER( ORDER BY votes_sum DESC )         - 1, 1, 3, 3, 5

select_clause = <<~SQL
  users.*,
  (
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(
      ORDER BY (
        SELECT SUM(cached_votes_score) FROM posts WHERE user_id = users.id
      ) DESC
    )
  ) as rank
SQL

@users = User.select( select_clause ).to_a # .order('rank').to_a if needed
@users.first.rank # 1
```

**Update**:

- You have to choose ranking function carefully, depending on rules,
  related to users with same amount of points.
- You have to cache `SUM(cached_votes_score)` in `users` table to avoid sub-select and speed-up the query

Answer (score 0):

Check this AR query:

```
Post.group(user_id).order('sum_votes DESC').sum(:votes_for)
```

Might need some modification

Answer (score 0):

I have read about AR and do something like this.

```
     @users= User.joins(:posts)
     .order("sum(cached_votes_score) 
     DESC").group("name").distinct
```

It works.

Thanks Pavel and Lun4i